# Error in casting List of Objects to List of the interface

Tags: java, android, interface, casting, wildcard

I have an interface in JAVA called ListItem and a class called Folder which implements it.
I have a List of Folder which I want to pass it to a method with List of ListItem argument.
here is that method:

```
List<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
public void addAll(List<ListItem> items) {
    this.items.beginBatchedUpdates();
    for (ListItem item : items) {
        items.add(item);
    }
    this.items.endBatchedUpdates();
}
```

For casting, I changed the argument to List of ? extends ListItem:

```
public void addAll(List<? extends ListItem> items) {
    this.items.beginBatchedUpdates();
    for (ListItem item : items) {
        items.add(item);
    }
    this.items.endBatchedUpdates();
}
```

Now there isn't any error in passing parameter, but I have an error in items.add(item) which says that you can't add ? extend ListItem to List of ListItem.
Why?
[image: Error]

Comment: Remember the difference between interface and class. You don't extend an interface, you implement it. The word extends is for parent classes to child classes.

Comment: Shouldn't `items.add(item);` be `this.items.add(item);`?

Comment: @Eran yeah, you are right, thank u!

Comment: You can't add a ListItem to that, because the real generic may be a child class of ListItem (`? extends ListItem`). What you probably wanted to do is adding the item to your member variable `items`, which you can access via `this.items`.

Answer (score 3):

Very simply, `List<? extends ListItem>` is a supertype of a whole lot of different types including `List<ListItem>`, `List<FancyListItem>`, `List<SuperExtraFancyListItem>` and so on, assuming `FancyListItem` and `SuperExtraFancyListItem` are subtypes of `ListItem`.

Now, what your code tries to do is to add a `ListItem` to a list that might be a `List<SuperExtraFancyListItem>`.  It really doesn't make sense to do that - this is a list whose elements are supposed to be `SuperExtraFancyListItem` objects, not just ordinary `ListItem`s.